Can a multi-threaded (pthreads) application have threads running on both CPUs of a dual socketed server? What impact on locks/memory latency?
I've seen server motherboards with two CPU sockets and I was wondering how such a server works. If the two sockets have to communicate with each other via some interface on the motherboard to maintain cache coherency, locks etc., doesn't that significantly increase memory latency? Or, does the OS keep a process confined to just one socket? I have no idea how such a setup works. I assume all the RAM is shared? The memory latency could affect the way an application should access memory to be performant so is a programming related question. Any relevant information is most welcome. I'm only asking out of curiosity as I've never had to code yet for such a system, but maybe one day.
NOTE: I'm referring to systems with two CPU sockets and dies, not just multi-core CPUs. Assume the multi-threaded application is written correctly to avoid data races on a single multi-core CPU system.

modern CPUs can have multiple dies inside, acting just like a multi-CPU system

For Xeon up to Broadwell, see https://frankdenneman.nl/2016/07/07/numa-deep-dive-part-1-uma-numa/ and later articles in that series (especially part 3, cache coherency; there are many options for how to config the snoop modes on Xeons with tradeoffs that are better for some workloads).   The QPI links are how one socket maintains cache-coherency with other sockets.  Broadwell was the last generation before Skylake Xeon, which changed the interconnect to a mesh instead of multiple rings.  Yes, latency is even higher for DRAM connected to other sockets.

Yes, All the RAM is shared between all cores on all sockets, and communication between threads on different sockets has higher latency. atomics and locks still work as expected (with higher latency if there is contention).
The operating system tries to keep all threads of an application running in a single socket to reduce latency, if you are not using many threads then you don't need to worry about it, and you don't need to update your code for it, CPU dies/sockets are usually transparent to the running application, and there are ways to manually limit applications to specific cores or socket or RAM sticks like numactl. and some applications manually pin threads to specific cores to improve performance but such applications easily become non-portable.
Even the newer AMD chips that have multiple CPU dies inside every chip benefitted from kernel updates to linux to improve performance because of the increased latency, which is why newer linux kernels are said to improve performance on systems with many sockets/dies.
One of the most relevant sources and benchmarks are in this video Non-Uniform Memory Architecture (NUMA): A Nearly Unfathomable Morass of Arcana - Fedor Pikus CppNow, with a note:

On NUMA systems, scaling is poor when thread count exceeds number of CPUs in a single node


in fact lots of modern CPUs are made in chiplet form, like AMD CCX and some new Intel tile technology. Each chiplet is in a single die and contains multiple cores, so they're exactly the same thing as multiple CPUs in a single motherboard. There's a NUMA NODES PER SOCKET settings in AMD UEFI to tune the performance for each usecase
